# Record Choice Set vs Picklist Choice Set in Flow Builder

Tags: visual-workflow

Could someone please enlighten me>>> what is the difference between record choice set and picklist choice set in Flow Builder?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The record choice set is driven by records in the database (a database query), while picklist choice is a list of options available from a field (metadata describe picklist values). Use the former when you want to allow users to select a record out of several different records, and the latter for choosing values from a picklist field.

Comment: Makes sense now. Thank you.